# Missing firmware on a Broadcom BCM4322

Tags: wireless, broadcom, firmware

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get a Broadcom BCM43XX working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/how-do-i-get-a-broadcom-bcm43xx-working)

I'm a new ubuntu user(11.10). I don't know how to connect wireless network. Could you possibly help me?

> Network 02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4322 802.11a/b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller [14e4:432b] (rev 01)

I'm so sorry to take your time, but thanks a lot!